# "their having a mind"

Tags: gerund-clauses, possessive-pronouns

> What, according to the functionalist, is the difference between things which merely have functional roles and things whose functional roles amount to **their** having a mind?
>
> Different people may interpret identical events or stimuli differently due to **their** having a mind that differs from your own.

Which part of English grammar stipulates using **their** in these sentences? For me it should be either "to **them** having a mind" or "to their having **of** a mind."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both constructions are acceptable.

Indeed for most of the 20th century only the construction with *their* would have been acceptable in formal discourse: *having* was by many ‘authorities’ regarded as a nominal form (a gerund) which could not take a subject but only a "possessor".

Today we by and large have a better understanding of how the language works. However, there are still old-school folks around who may be tolerant of explicitly objective forms in this position, but are still uncomfortable with it. I recommend using the genitive with pronouns, as in your examples, NOT because it’s in any sense more correct but because it avoids jarring any of your readers. Consider that they’re mostly old farts like me and may be in Very Senior Positions, and wait another twenty years: they’ll all be dead by then, or retired, and then you can do it your way.

Comment: To my ear "*due to their having **of** a mind that differs from your own*" sounds better. Would it be correct?

Comment: @Graduate It is grammatically justifiable but idiomatically flat wrong.

Comment: Some people (esp older ones) have a problem with the fact that language changes over time. I think the evidence suggests it's really just [a matter of **their/them** being behind the times*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+matter+of+them+being%2Ca+matter+of+their+being&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20matter%20of%20them%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20matter%20of%20their%20being%3B%2Cc0). I also think this is one of those rare occasions where the question is *very* incisive, and might be better posed on ELU.

Comment: ...in fact, as I now see, it *has* been [raised there](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/). But it's a good Q, and I bet you could give a better A.

Comment: @snailboat: Yes, but you see what I mean. This really *is* one of those Q's where it's good to see it on ELL, but it's not exactly trivial - even to native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I agree with your comments.  I didn't mean to imply otherwise!  (Sorry, I'm a bit out of it today, so I'm not sure exactly what I wrote.)