# Is "suggest" used correctly in "I strongly suggest your reading that book"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

The question is basically about the use of the verb "suggest" and the grammatical structure that accompanies it. I know that I can say "I suggest **that you** read that book" or
"I suggest **reading** that book", but I want to know if the expression "I suggest **your reading** that book" is correct.

Comment: What do you want 'I suggest your reading that book' to mean?

Comment: I don't think you can, but I don't know how to explain the grammar of it exactly. The construction you're trying to use (verb + possessive + gerund) doesn't work with "suggest" which needs an action. "Your reading that book" is more like a noun. "Your reading that banned book caused me to lose my job. I strongly suggest (that) you not read any more banned books."

Comment: This may help [Is 'his not having a name' grammatical correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/103597/9161)

Answer (score 1):

It is an expression that is probably correct.  I say "probably" because there is almost no situation in which you would actually use "I suggest your reading...".  It is always better to say "I suggest that you read..."

But a gerund/participle "reading" can have a subject in possessive form "your reading" (normally the subject is implied and omitted). I understand that meaning of the expression, but I would never use it.  So it marginally correct...but don't use it (unless you need it for poetic reasons etc.)