# Gerund form or infinitive

Tags: sentence-structure

Imagine you enjoy when someone speaks because of some personal habits that they do while speak and you want to mention that you like the way they peak. I was wondering if you could let me know if in the self-made sentence below, the gerund form would work better or the infinitive one:

> - I like him .......... like that way.
>
> a) speaking
>
> b) to speak

For me, they both work properly without any significant semantic change.

Comment: It should either be **"I like him speaking like that."** or **"I like him speaking that way."**. It would be wrong to say **"like that way"**.

Comment: @SovereignSun yes, you are absolutely right. It was a typo and I'm sorry for that. Thank you for pointing out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1: *I like him speaking like that <strike>way</strike>.*  (Note: [***his*** speaking](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/) is also acceptable, but less common)
>    When he speaks like that (which by implication he doesn't *always* do), I like it.
>
> 2: *I like him to speak like that.*
>    When he speaks like that (which by implication is under my control), I like it.
>
> 3: *I like the way he speaks.*
>    By implication, he *always* speaks like that, and it's a way of speaking that I like.

---

It's important to note that construction #2 usually carries the strong implication that the speaker himself is in control of whether or not the thing that he likes actually happens. It's a standard way of *explaining* a situation, as in *Why is it so hot in here? Because I like my house to be warm in winter*.