# Should 'his' or 'him' be used in this sentence?

Tags: personal-pronouns

> Up till now it seems that you have been experiencing his emotions, and sharing his thoughts, without **his** being any the wiser.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

The reason why I ask is that I saw [another example](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/none-the-wiser-any-the-wiser) from Collins dictionary, which uses 'you' instead of 'your'.

> We could have stolen the original from the warehouse without **you** being any the wiser.

So, I'd like to know if both 'his' and 'him' can work in this phrase? And any reasons?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RubioRic noted in the comment, [When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund) says:

> The basic "rule" is that formal written English prefers the possessive in all circumstances, while informal, conversational speech prefers the objective.

Given that the stories are set in and around a school in Britain with a long history, one would expect the language to lean towards the formal. Thus here the possessive is used, rather than the objective.

Answer (score 1):

> *Up till now it seems that you have been experiencing his emotions, and*
>   *sharing his thoughts, without* [*his being any the wiser]*.
>
> *We could have stolen the original from the warehouse without* [*you being*
>   *any the wiser*].

Yes, they are both fine. The subject of gerund-participial clauses like these can be either accusative or genitive; it's a free choice, though the genitive is characteristic of formal style.