# Which one is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

> - You are always complaining about me driving your car.
> - You are always complaining about I driving your car.
> - You are always complaining about my driving your car.

Comment: This is not a homework doing site, this site is to help you with your learning. What are your thoughts, why are you finding this difficult?

Comment: I’ve been finding it difficult because sometimes one thing is grammatically wrong nevertheless people say it. Even native speakers. I’m debating about those three and about “ you are always complaining about I am driving your car and you are always complaining that I am driving your car.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund) (Note that your *second* example is just completely invalid).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here.

The first guideline is that prepositions take third-person pronouns.
So one always **complains about me/him/her/them** and never about I/she/he/they.

So your second option **about I** is always wrong.

Many people, unaware of this rule, tend to say things like **from my wife and I**, which sounds more impressive but is wrong. If you turn the phrase around **from I and my wife** you see how wrong it is. We don't ever say **from I....**

But there is another consideration.

Traditionally, possessive adjectives were used before gerunds in the same way that they are still used before nouns.

> They don't like my singing/songs

But most native speakers these days say **they don't like me singing** instead. Most of the time the two constructions amount to the same thing. But there are times when the meaning changes, as in:

> They don't like my singing because I'm off key.
>   They don't like me singing so soon after my throat surgery.

The first refers to the quality of the singing. The second refers to the danger to my health.

In your examples, **complaining about me driving** is subtly different from **complaining about my driving**. Whereas the first complaint might concern your age or eye-sight, the second points to your bad driving. But both are idiomatic.

In an English test, I should use **my driving**.

Comment: Thank you, Ronald Sole. How about “ you always complain about I am driving your car / you always complain that I am driving your car?

Comment: @MarcioHenrique It looks like you may have accidentally created a second account. You might want to use the “Contact” link at the bottom of the page to have them merged so that you will be able to edit and comment on your question.