# Due to + pronoun + ing

Tags: grammar

Is it okay to write:

> The king didn't approve of her relationship with the prince **due to her coming** from a poor family.

I found the same phrase in a book from Google books from an actor that seemed to be American.

**The question is whether I can have a pronoun followed by a gerund after "due to" in that sentence or not.**

Here's the [link](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q="Due+to+her+coming+from"&num=10).

Comment: Did you mean to post a link to _search results_? Do you have a link to the book? Also, I believe this is a possible duplicate/related: [When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund).

Comment: What do you think the sentence should say instead? The question linked above isn't very relevant because *her* is used both as an object pronoun, as well as a possessive one, and so the case issue is obviated. Compare: *his ball* vs. ***her** ball*; *I like him* vs. *I like **her***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is okay and correct to say that.

**due to X** means **because of X**, so **X** is the reason for something. Because you're describing a reason, you need something that functions as a noun. "Coming from a poor family" can function as a noun, such as in the following sentences:

> **Coming from a poor family** gave John a keen appreciation for hard work.
>
> There is no shame in **coming from a poor family**.
>
> Mary's success in the business world shows that **coming from a poor family** doesn't mean you can't achieve great things.

How that we've seen that "coming from a poor family" can function as a noun, let's do a little experiment and actually replace it with a noun - e.g. "circumstances". Whose circumstances are we talking about? **Her** circumstances. So if we now undo the substitution we made, we end up with **her coming from a poor family**.

Plugging that back into the original sentence you provided, you get:

> The king didn't approve of her relationship with the prince **due to** her **circumstances**.
>
> ↓
>
> The king didn't approve of her relationship with the prince **due to** her **coming from a poor family**.

Answer (score 0):

Possessive pronouns are a type of determiner that can be used with nouns.  Gerunds, being noun-ish, work with them as well.

This doesn't apply to infinitives or participles.

> Due to her coming late, we all missed the show.
>
> We avoided the sidewalk being worked on and walked a different way (can't use possessive pronoun).
>
> I wanted to walk to the park.  (can't use possessive pronoun)
>
> I wanted her to walk to the park.  (English is being tricky here, *her* is an object pronoun and not a possessive pronoun)