# How can I combine this a couple of statements, using possessive with a gerund?

Tags: gerunds, possessives

> He plays his MP3 player in the library. I don't appreciate that.

While not being sure, I just guess it should be like below:

> I do not appreciate his playing his MP3 player in the library.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

> I do not appreciate his playing his MP3 player in the library.

is grammatically correct, although the first use of the possessive pronoun **his** may be considered out-of-place if the sentence is spoken rather than written (see these [related](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252272/is-i-hate-his-doing-that-old-fashioned/252508#252508) [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund)). Especially in modern spoken English, the following sentence may sound more natural:

> I do not appreciate **him** playing his MP3 player in the library.