# Are they all idiomatic: "French invasion of England" vs "France's invasion of England" vs "France's invading England" vs"France invading England"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, participles

Verbals such as "Someone's doing something" or "Someone doing something" are common. But when it comes to verbals in long structures, it gets confusing.

Here are some sample sentences with such structures.

1-She was against **French invasion of England.**

2-She was against **France's invasion of England.**

3-She was against **France's invading England.** (as in the case of "I don't mind **his living** with us.")

4-She was against **France invading England.** (as in the case of "I don't mind **him living** with us.")

In my opinion, they all seem to work grammatically. However, I am not sure whether they are all correct or interchangeable?

Comment: #1 is terrible, and #3 is pretty weird too, so you should avoid those. #4 is probably the most likely phrasing, which to my mind implies it's not unreasonable to assume #2 might have slightly different implications. Specifically, I think #2 more strongly implies *the invasion is real, and has either taken place already, or is imminent* (it might be an *extremely* hypothetical future possibility in #4 - certainly that form is unlikely to be used for an invasion that happened some time ago).

Comment: The first one is strange, and the third one is incorrect

Comment: You say the 3rd one is incorrect. Then look at this sentence: "I don't mind his living with us." This sentence is correct, isn't it. And it has same structure as "France's invading England.".

Comment: The devil is in the detail. #1 is unacceptable because it doesn't include the definite article before ***invasion***. It's still syntactically "valid" in principle without the article, but I maintain that stylistically it's ***terrible***. As to the object pronoun / possessive in *I don't mind **him/his** living with us*, that's been covered many times before. See [When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

> 1-She was against French invasion of England.
>
> 2-She was against France's invasion of England.
>
> 3-She was against France's invading England.
>
> 4-She was against France invading England.

in 1), French, an adjective, describes the invasion.  It answers the question: 'What kind of invasion?'.  Clearly, this is a weird question.

in 3), *invading* follows a possessive noun and hence has to be treated as a gerund.  We already have a noun **invasion**, so why do we need a gerund.  This is hence weird too.

2. and 4) are fine but have different meanings.

In 2), the focus is on the action, **invasion**.  'She is against the invasion.'

In 4), the focus is on the perpetrator, rather than the action.  'She is against France.'  *invading* is a participle modifying *France*.

Comment: Yes, *Russian* modifies *invasion*.  It is not wrong.  In the *French invasion* example, the context probably is clear that she was against an invasion, any invasions and not limited to the *French* type.  Adding the adjective is hence weird.