# How old are you—if you don’t mind me/my asking?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, possessive-pronouns

> How old are you—if you don’t mind me asking?

> How old are you—if you don’t mind my asking?

In TOEFL tests, 'my asking' was correct because 'my' is in a possessive case having 'asking' as an object, which is an orthodox grammar. But they say native English speakers also use 'me' a lot.

Which one is more used in spopken English among native speakers?

In a strict writing test, do I have to use 'my'?

Comment: Use 'my' in a test. It is more formal although many speakers would use 'me' in relaxed everyday conversation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund) There are ***many, many*** more questions on this specific point - have a look at the "Linked" questions on the one I'm citing in this closevote. Headline answer: *The basic "rule" is that formal written English prefers the possessive in all circumstances, while informal, conversational speech prefers the objective.*

Comment: I wouldn't have any respect for a test that marked non-native Anglophones down for using the objective. But if you need to pass an exam, maybe you have to abide by such pedantry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I'm actually surprised by the correct form for TOFEL. But I'm so sure that "If you don't mind me asking" is more common and I almost never heard "If you don't mind my asking" although it's not wrong.

Comment: It's not only 'not wrong', it is the correct version in formal English, as commenters have pointed out.

Comment: @KateBunting - In my youth, 'if you don't mind **my** asking' was a fixed polite phrase which one acquired by rote, and 'me asking' would have sounded odd, or would have been a sign of uncouthness.