# usage of gerunds

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, gerund-clauses

> I don't like him wasting time

vs

> I don't like his wasting time

what is the difference in meaning of these two sentences

Comment: The first is used as a participle. In the second, the noun phrase is more usual as "I don't like his time-wasting."

Comment: @WeatherVane so are both correct? Could you please elaborate what does first sentence mean?

Comment: In the first sentence, he is wasting time, and that is what you don't like: you don't like him [when he is] wasting time. Your second sentence is grammatical but not idiomatic. It could be said when "he is malnourished and wasting away, and I don't like those times when he is losing weight." But that isn't your intention, I am sure, to use it like "partying time" or "waiting time".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund) See also [“their having a mind”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13311/their-having-a-mind/13312#13312), and doubtless others.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I disagree. Both versions are in common use today, with no difference in meaning.

Comment: Note that in some contexts, the two are not exchangeable because they mean different things. For example: **I don't like him singing while his throat is sore**. And **I don't like his singing; it's out of tune.**

Comment: You can say "I don't like his wasting of time"

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. In both cases "him/his wasting time" is a clause with "him"/"his" as subject and the verb phrase "wasting time" as predicate.